# Enable 32-bit applications in IIS 7 using VS2010 deployment capabilities

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, msdeploy, web-deployment

I want to deploy the WCF service (.net 4.0) to IIS 7 and use the built in deployment capabilities of Visual Studio 2010 for this. There is a good article about that on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx but there is still one unclear thing for me.

I want to set "enable 32 bit applications" app pool setting during deployment and it seems like there is a special option to do this in Package/Publish Web section of visual studio project. There are two checkboxes there, namely:  "Include all IIS settings as configured in IIS" and "Include application pool settings used by this Web project". But when I select them, build a deployment package and deploy it to IIS on different computer then "enable 32 bit applications" is not set in the target environment (WCF service itself is installed successfully and working).

Probably I'm missing something or misunderstood the intention of IIS settings inside the VS2010 project. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am deploying a site to GoDaddy and I cannot change this setting and it is preventing me from using ChilKatDotNet45, as the 64-Bit version will not run, and the 32-Bit will only work in IIS if I have the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" set to True for my App Pool.